# Def help, trying to define pieces of code

Tags: python

Not sure if/or how to do this, excuse the mess I'm new.

If I can get something like this to work it would clear a lot of my code.

Thanks in advance

```
def on()
GPIO.output(4, 0)
def off()
GPIO.output(4, 1)

On
Off
```

Comment: you need to do a python tutorial to get the basics down...head over to codecademy.com or something similiar – luke_aus just now   edit

Comment: I apologize for being new, and trying to get help on a piece of code.  I researched and thought I'd get better results from asking. Sorry for wasting your time. I shall go read Python for dummies

Answer (score 0):

You should research how to define Python functions. First, on the `def` statement after the parentheses, add a colon at the very end of the line. Next, all code inside your function must be indented. Third, to call the function, you need to put parentheses at the end.